# Dynamically Embed a FAQ Page Schema at end of WordPress Post Content using a shortcode or maybe via wordpress hooks "after-cotent" or "after-footer"

Tags: wordpress, schema, hook, shortcode

Any assistance or insights is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the format of the FAQ Page Schema I want to be embedded.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [
    {
      "@type": "Question",
      "name": "Question #1",
      "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Answer to Question #1 <a href='#ID#1-of-H2-HTML-TAG'>... Read More</a>"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Question",
      "name": "Question #2",
      "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Answer to Question #2 <a href='#ID#2-of-H2-HTML-TAG'>... Read More</a>"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Question",
      "name": "Question #n",
      "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Answer to Question #n <a href='#ID#n-of-H2-HTML-TAG'>... Read More</a>"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Assumptions: All of my blog posts will have at least 1 SUB-SECTION and each SUB-SECTION are H2 tag. It will have the following format once the LuckyWP Table of Contents plugin has done its processing. The span & id is inserted by LuckyWP.

```
<h2><span id="How-do-I-change-colors">How do I change colors?</span></h2>
<p>The majority of Volumes colors are controlled by the Customizer. There are some Elements that are part of Volumes features that require CSS. This article covers where to make those changes:</p>
```

So to fill up the variables:

"name": "Question #n"
Question #n will be the H2 Text, in this case, "How do I change colors?"

"text": "Answer to Question #n ... Read More"

Answer to Question #n - Excerpt the 15 words from the paragraph tag following right after the  tag.

... Read More - is the 2nd part on the answer. It is an internal hyperlink that links directly to the H2 tag. You will be using the span id of this  tag entry that was inserted by LuckyWP. This is what it should output.

```
<a href='#How-do-I-change-colors'>... Read More</a>
```